# java generic array and Classcast exception

Tags: java, arrays, generics, classcastexception

I had declared BinaryTree as below :

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {}
```

But when I call

```
Character[] actual = binaryTreeChar.preOrderTraversal(root, Character[].class);
```

it is throwing exception as below.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [[Ljava.lang.Character; cannot be cast
>   to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;

Is there any better way to deal these cases ?

```
public T[] preOrderTraversal(BinaryNode<T> root, Class<T[]> clazz) {
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, count);
        Stack<BinaryNode<T>> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(root);
        int i = 0;
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            BinaryNode<T> next = stack.pop();
            array[i++] = next.data;
            if (next.right != null)
                stack.push(next.right);
            if (next.left != null)
                stack.push(next.left);
        }
        return array;
    }


}
```

Comment: @PeterBruins Realized that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
public T[] preOrderTraversal(BinaryNode<T> root, Class<T> clazz)
```

And:

```
Character[] actual = binaryTreeChar.preOrderTraversal(root, Character.class);
```

As it is now, you are creating an instance of a `Character[][]` (i.e. a two dimensional array).

The `Class` passed to `Array.newInstance` is the component type of the array, not the array type.

> **Object java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class componentType, int length) throws NegativeArraySizeException**
>
> Creates a new array with the specified component type and length...
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **componentType** the Class object representing the component type of the new array
>   **length** the length of the new array